# Xcode 5 layout errors - Misplaced View Frame for Label will be different at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, layout, xcode5

I just installed Xcode 5 and I am currently preparing my apps for release to the App Store on iOS 7 next week. I am getting a whole bunch of errors and warnings though.

In one app where I have a UIPickerView, UITextFields and a bunch of UILabels. In this app it gives an `Illegal Configuration` (red) error on almost all controls in the storyboard file. I don't know what that error is or how to fix it. I would appreciate some help on that. I can't completely recreate the file because there are 20 complicated views.

In another app there is a UIScrollView containing a bunch of UILabels and UITextFields, plus one UITextView that is created programmatically and contains text based on what you selected in a (previous view) UITableView as well as resizing itself to fit the content. The UIScrollView resizes to accommodate for the new size of the UITextView. This one compiles and builds and the UITextView gets created but doesn't contain the text, probably because it now resizes incorrectly. The UIScrollView now also scrolls horizontally in addition to vertically which it isn't supposed to. This one gives only (yellow) warnings which all say:

`Misplaced View Frame for "Label - Symbol:" will be different at run time.` 
for 4 controls including this Label and another, a Text Field and the Scroll View.

I would appreciate any help on this because this is the first time for me adjusting to a new version of Xcode and iOS.

P.S: Details on the `Illegal Configuration` error include:
`Auto Layout on iOS Versions prior to 6.0`

Thanks!

Comment: Check here : https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're still looking for an answer here, the answer is likely that you have either no constraints, or improper constraints, on your AutoLayout view.

You can fix this by selecting the view and going to the Xcode menu option: `Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Add Missing Constraints / Reset to Suggested Constraints`.

You can also select the entire layout and do the same thing, this will reset all of the views on your layout to recommended constraints.

If you need to do custom constraints, you will have to set up your own auto layout constraints either in the Storyboard/XIB file, or manually in code.

For more information about Auto Layout, you can see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Finally, you can also turn off auto layout on the layout if you want it to appear as-is, with no automatic readjustments (this is not recommended).

[image]

Comment: This does seem like the most reasonable answer even thought it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: And for ambiguous Layout?

Comment: In that case, try reset to suggested constraints. That means that some of your constraints conflict or are not specific enough.

Answer (score 15):

`Reset to Suggested Constraints` sometimes does not get rid of this warning. The solution is to select `Placeholder` in the `Intrinsic Size` drop down menu in the Size inspector of the UIView in question. And then add the missing constraints as needed.

Comment: In NSTableView, it is consists of Scroll View and Clip View followed by Table View, I did turn off the warning message once I enable the 'Placeholder' size in Scroll View (although Clip View is emitting the warning message).

Answer (score 3):

Simply select your view controller Go to

Editor-->Resolve Autolayout issues--> Clear All Constraints in ViewController and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Frame "Label frame will be different at run time" -- Please see the release notes under Autolayout: Runtime.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051

Full answer will be shown here after the NDA is lifted.

Note: this also happens under Xcode 4.2 as well, but the problem isn't surfaced by IB.

Comment: Has the NDA been lifted yet? :)

Comment: @VictorEngel emmmm... Yes actually, if you haven't noticed yet!

Comment: Oops. I forgot my sarcasm markup. :) (actually, that's what the smiley was for)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode now works with relative position against parent views. You can correct them to click on the orange lines and click on the mark and select use storyboard value or something

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can switch off Auto Layout altogether.

This approach comes in handy if you want to be compatible with iOS 5.

Comment: Considering that more than 75+% of iOS devices run iOS 7, I highly doubt anyone goes for compatibility with older versions of iOS.

Comment: I do - I like my iPad 1 audience ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error in the two text fields I added in View controlller. What helped me to resolve the issue is:
In the document Outline,I *Ctr+dragged* the 1st text field up to the View and selected **Center Horizontally in Container**. Then I *Ctr+dragged* the 2nd text field up to the View and selected **Center Vertically in Container**.
Hope this helps you too.