# Make Xcode 5 find all misplaced views

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've just transitioned a storyboard-using project from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5, and have a whole bunch of Misplaced View warnings. However, Xcode seems to be a little shy about showing them to me. As I scroll around the storyboard and select things, Xcode adds these warnings to the Issue Navigator - and then, if I'm not quick to jump on them, *removes* them again without me actually changing anything. I haven't even figured out what actions trigger the warnings appearing and disappearing. This is really annoying - at one point there were about 20 warnings in there that promptly vanished before I could address them.

I'd like to track all these issues down and address them, but I don't know how. What causes Xcode to add and remove these warnings to the Issue Navigator, and how can I track them all down when Xcode keeps hiding them from me?

Answer (score 7):

I would go ahead and take a snapshot before you do this:

1. Click on your XIB file
2. Expand the dock
3. Look along the right edge of the dock and you should see some yellow circle icons
4. Click on the circle, it will change into a triangle
5. Click on the triangle

You should see some radio buttons enabling you to update the constraints and a checkbox to apply the changes globally.

Click in "Fix Misplacement" and you should go back to "No Issues".

Comment: What does the dock mean? Is it equals to Document Outline on the left side of Storyboard? I couldn't find any yellow circle icons on my Xcode.

Comment: To expand the dock, click on the small arrow pointing to the right on the lower left conner of the storyboard. Tooltip on it reads 'Show Document outline'

Comment: -1; no, this doesn't address my question at all, and it's irritating that it's been upvoted. I already know how to *resolve* misplaced views - I asked how to find them. The dock lists the same set of misplaced views that the issue navigator does. The problem I described in the question is that Xcode fails to find most of my misplaced views upon first loading the storyboard (they don't appear either in the dock or the issue navigator) and only shows them when I scroll around the storyboard and select things. This remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

`Reset to Suggested Constraints` sometimes does not get rid of this warning. The solution is to select `Placeholder` in the `Intrinsic Size` drop down menu in the `Size inspector` of the UIView in question. And then add the missing constraints as needed.

(taken from here : [Xcode 5 layout errors - Misplaced View Frame for Label will be different at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739572/xcode-5-layout-errors-misplaced-view-frame-for-label-will-be-different-at-runt) )

Comment: -1; like the other answer, this doesn't address *the question I asked*, which is how to make all the warnings on a large converted storyboard show up at once rather than them appearing and disappearing at random as I scroll around the storyboard.